# Looping Objects Object to check isit the value same as my variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

can anyone show me on solve this js algorithm ? i am reaching nested objects object to check isit the categories value same as my variable and if true return those object match the value back. not sure if i am using the right way, but also not sure how to return the whole objects back.

**objects**

```
const data = [
    {
      "id": 799,
      "name": "Ship Your Idea",
      "slug": "ship-your-idea-22",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/ship-your-idea-22/",
       "categories": [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 794,
      "name": "Premium Quality",
      "slug": "premium-quality-19",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-19/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "T-shirts",
          "slug": "t-shirts"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 795,
      "name": "Premium Quality2",
      "slug": "premium-quality-193",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-193/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**my functions**

```
 const brand = 'clothing';

  function fliterProductByCategorly(obj, brand){
    // 1.loop through each objects object
    // 2.loop through object and get categorie
    // 3.categorie filter get slug
    // 4.check if slug value are same value as global slug, if do only return object that match the brand value.

    return Object.entries(obj).filter(([, {categories}]) => Object.entries(categories).filter(([, {slug}]) => slug == brand ))
  }

  console.log(fliterProductByCategorly(data, brand))
```

sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pizeq4

Comment: @cmgchess Yeah, but i need to check the each categories slug to see if it match the brand variable. it might be having more but i want to keep it simple to solve it first.

Comment: @cmgchess lolz yes, but why isit no need to loop to the categories to get the slug, i though it needed somehow. haha i should keep it simple to solve it.

Comment: after study your code, it make prefect sense now XD, very greatful mate !

Comment: my method wont work if categories array has more than 1 element

Comment: Yeah but is good for now, haha i will remember how to use this next time for such nested object check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that categories array has only 1 element

```js
const data = [
    {
      "id": 799,
      "name": "Ship Your Idea",
      "slug": "ship-your-idea-22",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/ship-your-idea-22/",
       "categories": [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 794,
      "name": "Premium Quality",
      "slug": "premium-quality-19",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-19/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "T-shirts",
          "slug": "t-shirts"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 795,
      "name": "Premium Quality2",
      "slug": "premium-quality-193",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-193/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const brand = 'clothing';

  function fliterProductByCategorly(obj, brand){
    return obj.filter(e => e.categories[0].slug===brand)
  }

  console.log(fliterProductByCategorly(data, brand))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Possible implementation using reduce if categories contains more than 1 element.

```js
const data = [
    {
      "id": 799,
      "name": "Ship Your Idea",
      "slug": "ship-your-idea-22",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/ship-your-idea-22/",
       "categories": [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 794,
      "name": "Premium Quality",
      "slug": "premium-quality-19",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-19/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "T-shirts",
          "slug": "t-shirts"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 795,
      "name": "Premium Quality2",
      "slug": "premium-quality-193",
      "permalink": "https://example.com/product/premium-quality-193/",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "name": "T-shirts",
          "slug": "t-shirts"
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Clothing",
          "slug": "clothing"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  
  const brand = 'clothing';

  function fliterProductByCategorly(obj, brand){
    return obj.reduce((acc,curr) => {
        if (curr.categories.filter(e => e.slug===brand).length>0){
        acc.push(curr)
      }
      return acc;
    },[])
  }

  console.log(fliterProductByCategorly(data, brand))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you elaborate some specially the .length part, i dont get that part. is the length part check after the filter or before the filter ?

Comment: i did the length > 0 part to check if the filtered array is not empty which means that the clothing category exists in the array

Comment: filter returns an array and if it empty means clothing category not found otherwise if it has an element it means clothing category is found

Comment: @cmgcheess so the length is to make sure it dont not give it back a empty array after filter out, i think i get the whole process of your algorithm, make me learn more :D. thanks for the help and the elaboration mate, very greatful for your help !

Comment: actually i checked the length to see if the category exist in the array